# Plotly colored bars for bar graph

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, rgb, plotly-python

I'm trying to get the bar graph to utilize a string of an `rgb` color that is generated and unique for each state. I can't seem to get the graph to utilize the actual rgb value as the color it renders. It currently changes from the default coloring to different colors, and displays the rgb string in the legend. I am using the `color_dict` in other places in my app, so that's why I'm attempting to have it be "global" and not within the function `incident_by_state`. Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['TX', 'TX', 'CA', 'WI', 'TX'],
    'incident_type': ['Fire', 'Fire', 'Storm', 'Snow', 'Fire']
})

color_dict = {}
for i, state in enumerate(df_main['state'].unique()):
  color = 'rgb(' + ','.join(map(str, [((i + 5) * 71) % 255, ((i + 5) * 83) % 255, ((i + 5) * 97) % 255])) + ')'
  color_dict[state] = color

def incident_by_state(filter):
  incidents_by_state = (
      filter.groupby(by=["state"]).count()[["incident_type"]].sort_values(by="incident_type") 
  )

  fig_incidents_by_state = px.bar(
    incidents_by_state,
    y=incidents_by_state.index,
    x="incident_type",
    labels={"incident_type": "No. Incidents", "state": "State"},
    color=incidents_by_state.index.map(color_dict),
    color_discrete_map=color_dict,
    title="Total Incidents in each State")

  fig_incidents_by_state.update_layout(
      yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed")
  )
  return fig_incidents_by_state
```

Like I said above, the colors are not rendering to what the rgb string is representative of. I was expecting specific colors based on those values. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `color_dict` maps each state to a unique color, you should pass the `states` to `color` instead of the colors themselves. Then the argument `color_discrete_map=color_dict` will take care of the mapping between the state and its color.

```
fig_incidents_by_state = px.bar(
    incidents_by_state,
    y=incidents_by_state.index,
    x="incident_type",
    labels={"incident_type": "No. Incidents", "state": "State"},
    color=incidents_by_state.index,
    color_discrete_map=color_dict,
    title="Total Incidents in each State")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want plotly to control the colors though. I want it to pull from my pre defined set of colors for each state. I'm looking for a way to force it to use the colors in my color_dict.

Comment: these aren't plotly's predefined colors – these are from `color_dict` as defined in the code sample you included in your question